# Missing required parameters - Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I know this question might be repeated multiple times but, I've tried my best to solve this problem.. None of the solutions I saw helped me and I don't know what to do I'm still a beginner in Laravel.

I'm trying to build a route which contains 3 parameters (slug/season number/episode number)
So the url would be like this: 
 
**/series/watch/{slug}/season/{season_number}/episode/{episode_number}**

Every time I try a new solution I'm still getting the same error!

Here my code:

web.php:

```
Route::get('/series/watch/{tvshow:slug}/season/{season:season_number}/episode/{episode:episode_number}', [TvShowsController::class, 'watch'])->name('Series.Watch');
```

Controller:

```
public function watch(TvShow $tvshow, Season $season, Episode $episode){
        $season = Season::where('tv_show_id', '=', $tvshow)->get();
        $episode = Episode::where('tv_show_id', '=', $tvshow)->where('season_id', '=', $season);

        return view('series.watch', [
            'tvshow' => $tvshow,
            'season' => $season,
            'episode' => $episode
        ]);
    }
```

and this is what is think the problem is:
the view:

```
<a href="{{ Route('Series.Watch', ['tvshow' => $tvshow, 'season' => $tvshow->seasons->first()->season_number, 'episode' => $tvshow->seasons->first()->episodes->first()->episode_number]) }}" class="btn"></a>
```

Cna you help me please?

Comment: What's the error you are getting? Show it

Comment: @GazmendSahiti here it is: `Missing required parameters for [Route: Series.Watch] [URI: series/watch/{tvshow}/season/{season}/episode/{episode}] [Missing parameters: season, episode].`

Comment: Shouldnt you pass the slug not the object? tvshow' => $tvshow->slug

Comment: @Peppermintology What do you mean by that? I'm getting the values from the db if that's what you mean.

Comment: @WNR it works find without the season and the episode parameters and it's not complaining about that, but I've tried to set it as you say and still the same problem.

Comment: Do they actually have a value or are they empty (i.e. what is the actual return value of `$tvshow->seasons->first()->season_number`)?

Comment: @Peppermintology They are coming from th db as intgers and yes they do have a value not just an empty one. But I'm not quite sure that I've wrote the correct code to access the first value of a season when tv_show_id is the same.